# From OSM data to shape file. Parsing issue

Tags: java, android, kml, openstreetmap, shapefile

I'm working at OpenStreetMap project for android at the moment. I want to retrieve OSM data from my app(nodes, markers and paths) and convert it to shape file (.shp, .dbf and .shx). Later, I'll load it into ArcGIS editor.

I've been investigating about it, and I have no clear idea if It's possible a direct conversion between this formats, or I have to  step first on KML file and parse it in shape file.
I actually don't know how to retrieve the OSM data to save a osm file for being treated. I've been looking for a library or something like that but I have no lucky.

Can anyone give me a helping hand?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this help.. https://sourceforge.net/projects/osm2shpjava/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately there's no converter existing between those formats. Even to make a KML file you will have to make your own KML parser.

Comment: Oh, as I feared :\ So I think I'll have to save the osm file, parse it to KML and later, another parse step to shape file.

How can I save the osm file into my device? I have encountered several web examples, but nothing for java android or some avaiable api :s

Comment: You use the osmdroid api in your app to display those markers and path and have access to all those objects, right? In this case you should have all the data to save a KML file, or other format as you whish if you make the corresponding parser.  For KML a tutorial exists, in french unfortunately, here: http://thibault-koprowski.fr/2011/10/14/tutoriel-android-comment-parser-du-xml-v2/

Comment: Ok, so I have to create my own items parser to kml, and later, another one parser, KML to Shape this time, am I heading the right direction?

In that case, may I use simple XML lib to work on it? http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php

Comment: SimpleXml is the easiest way to implement it. For really big files sax is mostly used as it is faster but in your case, files shouldn't be too big.